# Access multiple dictionaries inside a list of a json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe from a json code. But I cannot access multiple objects inside a list. Only the first value is being retrieved.

This is my json code:

```
[{'id': '1', 'fnamae': 'Rasab', 'lname': 'Asdaf', 'Age': 21, 'Language': ['python', 'json'], 'parents': {'mother': {'name': 'Mrs. Mother', 'phone': '1212121212'}, 'father': {'name': 'Mr. Father', 'phone': '1212121212'}}, 'siblings': [{'name': 'jamuna', 'phone': 564851312}, {'name': 'Killana', 'phone': 1212121212}]}, {'id': '2', 'fnamae': 'Muddassir', 'lname': 'Jameel', 'Age': 25, 'Language': ['React', 'json'], 'parents': {'mother': {'name': 'Mrs. Mutherinlaw', 'phone': 9654512}, 'father': {'name': 'Mr. Futherinlaw', 'phone': 53154278}}, 'siblings': [{'name': 'Giallan', 'phone': 998742568}, {'name': 'Simba', 'phone': 12355875}]}, {'id': '3', 'fnamae': 'Farhan', 'lname': 'Akhtar', 'Age': 25, 'Language': ['Drupal', 'PHP'], 'parents': {'mother': {'name': 'Heung min son', 'phone': 89546487}, 'father': {'name': 'Kane', 'phone': 4564823545}}, 'siblings': [{'name': 'Xamcs', 'phone': 78654325}, {'name': 'sinfbad', 'phone': 45648232}]}]
```

And this is my code to access "siblings" list from the json files to create a dataframe.

```
s = l['siblings']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(s.str[0].values.tolist())
df2
```

But the output is:

```
    name    phone
0   jamuna  564851312
1   Giallan 998742568
2   Xamcs   78654325
```

My expected output would be to include the multiple names and phone numbers of the siblings.

```
    name              phone
0   [jamuna,Killana]  564851312,468451
1   [Giallan,Simba]   998742568,654684
2   [Xamcs, sinfbad]  786543254,654654
```

When I change my code to s.str[1] I am able to retrieve the second set of list. But how do I iterate over them

Comment: Could you post your expected output?

Comment: I have updated my expected output. I don't need exactly like that. But multiple values need to come under the columns.

Comment: Thanks, very clear :) I'm not sure there's a "clean" way to do this, but I've posted a solution which should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to do a nested list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
    {
        key: [[j[key] for j in i["siblings"]] for i in json_content]
        for key in ["name", "phone"]
    }
)
```

This will give you

```
|    | name                  | phone                   |
|---:|:----------------------|:------------------------|
|  0 | ['jamuna', 'Killana'] | [564851312, 1212121212] |
|  1 | ['Giallan', 'Simba']  | [998742568, 12355875]   |
|  2 | ['Xamcs', 'sinfbad']  | [78654325, 45648232]    |
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what i wanted. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to derive the output

```
pd.DataFrame([d for l in json_content for d in l['siblings']])
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need the values under 3 columns. The names of a list should come together. I have updated my expected output.